# Right align element in a div only with relative property

Tags: html, css

Right now I am practicing on creating a header section, which contains an image which is used as a logo and and a un-ordered list which is used as a navigation menu.
Both of these elements are kept in a div element and I want to align the image to the left in the div element and the un-ordered list to the right of the div element. So how can I do it?
Second, I am willing only to use relative property. Not 'Absolute'! As I want to align the list vertically in the middle of the div element and with position absolute I am unable to vertically align the list with vertical align property.
if I am using float than the same situation is there. I am unable to vertically align the list to the middle, which I want to do.
So, I just want to know how can I position my list to the right of the div element using the relative positioning property.

```css
<style>
.header-section {
  background-color:red;
}
ul {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}
ul li {
  display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="header-section">
    <img src="some-image.jpg">
    <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
     <li>About Us</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` to parent div and give `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.header-section
{
background-color:red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
ul
{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
}
ul li
{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="header-section">
    <img src="some-image.jpg">
    <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
     <li>About Us</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ketan! flex property with space between worked out. Also 'align-items' property helps me align the content to the center(vertically). Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that:

Support is IE10 and Up.

```css
.header-section {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-section">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-50-50-8.jpg">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution will be using float, like the snippet below:

```css
.header-section{
  background-color:red;
}

ul{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}

ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}

.header-section img{
  float: left;
}

.header-section ul {
  float: right;
}
.header-section p {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   <div class="header-section">
      <img src="some-image.jpg">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
      </ul>
      <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice I added a paragraph element to clear the floats.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) like this:

```
ul {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    float: right;
}

img {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```css
.header-section {
  background: red url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2/') no-repeat left center;
  background-size: contain;
  text-align: right;
}
ul {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}
ul li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```